# Adding trailing slash to URL with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

i have a input field that is accepting url from user and i need to check for trailing slash like so:

- www.example.com (add slash)
- www.exaple.com/ (ignore)
- www.example.com/index.php (ignore)

How could i achieve this in javaScript?

PS .htaccess and php are not the options

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you running into trouble? Have you at least read through the various `String` functions? [MDC has a decent page on `String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)

Comment: well problem here is i know how to check if there is smth at the end of of string (slash in this case) the problem is that i cant figure out how can i check whether i need to add it in or  not depending on the structure of the link

Comment: Did you try regular expressions to determine if the slash is needed?

Comment: im guessing this is the way to go but unfortunately i don't know regexp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
function URLFormat() {
    var url = document.getElementById('inputURL').value;
    var urlParts = url.split("/")
    var result = '';
    for (i = 0; i < urlParts.length; i++) {
        if (i == urlParts.length - 1) {
            if (urlParts[i].indexOf('.') > -1) {
                // trailing slash not required
                result = url;
            }
            else {
                if (urlParts[i].indexOf('#') > -1) {
                    // trailing slash not required
                    result = url;
                }
                else {
                    //Assume this is a folder and add a slash
                    result = url + '/';
                }
            }
        }
    }
    alert(result);
}
```

Comment: Happy that I was able to help you, but could you post modification you had to do ? Just for my reference, if anything was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = "http://www.example.com";
var hasTrailingSlash = input.charAt(input.length - 1) === "/";
```

Comment: this doesen't solve the problem with the third example because by this check it would say i need a slash there.

Comment: The other problem here is query strings: `http://www.example.com/lol?utm_campaign=pain_to_lick`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function func(url) {
     var domain = url.split("/")[0];
     var answer;
     if(url == domain){
       answer = url + "/";
     } else {
       answer = url;
     }
     alert(answer);
}
```

Comment: The trailing slash disappears with the split and how will this handle http://www.server.com/subfolder ?